# How to add scores to the names they correspond to

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop, sum

I am writing a code that uses functions (not arrays) to create a program that is an American Idol style voting system. I'm not using arrays because I really need to master functions first.

There are 5 votes per contestant, dropping the highest and lowest and averaging the final 3 to get an answer, whoever has the highest average wins. However, number of contestants is based off of user input (possibly infinite amount of contestants)

I am unaware on how to get an average for each individual student, only as a mass, and as of now, my program only takes the last input values as the winner. Here is my code.

If there is any help on how to get different averages for different contestants, please let me know, I'm new to functions, and pretty new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void validCheck();
void calcAvgCheck();
void findHigh();
void findLow();

ofstream outputFile;
ofstream inputFile;
double totalScore, average, score;
string name;

int main(){
    int judge = 1;
    outputFile.open("contestant.txt");
    while (name != "done" || name != "Done"){
        cout << "Enter Contestant Name, if no more, type 'done': ";
        cin >> name;

        outputFile << name << " ";

        if (name == "done" || name == "Done"){ break; }
        for (judge = 1; judge < 6; judge++){
            cout << "Enter score " << judge << " ";
            validCheck();
            outputFile << " " << score << " ";
            calcAvgCheck();
        }
    }

    cout << "Winner is: " << name << "with a score of: " << average;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void validCheck(){
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 1 || score > 10){
        cout << "Please Enter a score between 1 and 10: ";
        cin >> score;
    }
    totalScore += score;
}

void calcAvgCheck(){
    inputFile.open("contestant.txt");

    average = totalScore / 5;
}
```

Comment: as long as you are using `c++`, you should avoid stray functions . please hold all global members as `class members`, and global functions as `class functions` then you can use class array of objects and treat each array member as a separate contestant

Comment: @Youssef: This "everything has to be a member function" myth just won't die, will it? There is nothing wrong with free functions and, in many circumstances, [they _increase_ encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Answer (score 0):

Function    `calcAvgCheck();` should call outside for loop.

You can save score in a vector   and can reuse for calculating avg as follows.

Please note defining global values is not a good practice. I know there are more work needed , and it should be your homework. Please proceed from here and if you have more questions, please post a  different question as continuation of this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

void validCheck();
double calcAvgCheck(std::vector<int>& scores);
void findHigh();
void findLow();


double totalScore, score;
string name;

int main(){
    int judge = 1;
    vector<int> scores;
    double  average =0.0;

    while (name != "done" || name != "Done"){
        cout << "Enter Contestant Name, if no more, type 'done': ";
        cin >> name;

        if (name == "done" || name == "Done"){ break; }
        for (judge = 1; judge < 6; judge++){
            cout << "Enter score " << judge << " ";
            validCheck();
            scores.push_back(score);
        }
        average =calcAvgCheck(scores);
        std::cout<< " average:"<< average<<"\n";
    }

    cout << "Winner is: " << name << "with a score of: " << average;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void validCheck(){
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 1 || score > 10){
        cout << "Please Enter a score between 1 and 10: ";
        cin >> score;
    }
    totalScore += score;
}
double  calcAvgCheck( std::vector<int>& scores)
 {
        int sum=0;
        for(auto &x : scores)
           sum+=x;
        return sum/scores.size();
 }
```

Comment: Should i even use my files? I was using them to try and read information back, will the vector do better?

Comment: I hope you may prefer to keep the individual score in file, if it is not your concern, no need of a file in this program

Comment: I dont need it then, I don't care about saving it to the file, I am getting some debug errors with your edit to the code though, let me post them...

warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'const int', possible loss of dataerror C2660: 'calcAvgCheck' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: The edited code as of now: for (judge = 1; judge < 6; judge++){
  cout << "Enter score " << judge << " ";
  validCheck();
   scores.push_back(score);}
  calcAvgCheck();
  double avg = calcAvgCheck(scores);
  cout << "avg: " << avg;}

cout << "Winner is: " << name << "with a score of: " << average;
system("pause");
return 0;}
void validCheck(){
cin >> score;
if (score < 1 || score > 10){
cout << "Please Enter a score between 1 and 10: ";
cin >> score;}
totalScore += score;}

double calcAvgCheck(vector<int>& scores){
 int sum = 0;
 for (auto &x : scores)
  sum += x;
 return sum / scores.size();}

Comment: @Ace Ebert I rewrote my answer, if it helps please accept the answer